# Make sure in same (EDT) event dispatching thread

Tags: java, swing

I have a main class:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
       Main m = new Main();
       m.initGUI(); 
      }
 }); 
 public void initGUI() {
   //add components for this JFrame
   //add JPanel with table
   //etc..
   this.pack();
   this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   this.setVisible(true);
  }
```

}

then I have a class which extends JPanel:

```
class CTable extends JPanel {
  JTable table;
   public void initGUI() {
  //add components, table to JPanel etc...
  //action listeners to table
 }
 public void handleTableRowOnClick(String data) { 
   InfoDialog d = new InfoDialog(data);
   //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
   //do something else here (THIS SHOULD EXECUTE BUT IT DOESN'T) such as:
   String test = "test"
   //(IT ONLY EXECUTES AFTER I CLOSE THE DIALOG)
    //and I need the ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL functionality
 } 
}
```

then I have another class:

```
class InfoDialog extends JDialog {
  JComboBox cb;
  String data;
   public void initGUI() { 
    //add components such as JComboBox
    //etc...
    this.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    this.setTitle("test");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
  }
  public InfoDialog(String data) {
   this.data = data;
   this.initGUI();
  }

}
```

My question is what is the best method in this situation to make sure InfoDialog instance is in the same event dispatching thread (EDT)?

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: What do you mean by the _same_ event dispatching thread?  There's only 1 EDT. (Or have I misunderstood your true question).

Comment: I mean for InfoDialog, I'm not calling SwingUtilities.invokeLater in its initGUI. Do I need to in this case?

Comment: I understand there is only 1 EDT, how can I make sure for InfoDialog that its in the same one. I must be going crazy by now after all the hours spent debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to check `EventQueue.isDispatchingThread` BEFORE you create the dialog...

```
public void handleTableRowOnClick(final String data) { 
    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            InfoDialog d = new InfoDialog(data);
        }
    }
    if (EventQueue.isDispatchingThread()) {
        runner.run();
    } else {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runner);
    }
}
```

As I said in you previous question, it should the responsibility of the caller to ensure that the code is executed correctly not your components.

Comment: I have updated my question inside the handleTableRowOnClick() method which was causing all my problems. Please look at comments inside that method. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Unfortunetely I have tried this and it doesn't work. It still hangs the dialog and prevents subsequent execution.

Comment: @lcplusplus Then make your dialog non-modal: `dialog.setModal(false)` before showing it and make sure to provide a proper "parent" `Window` in the constructor to avoid the "go-behind" effect.

Comment: Hi Guilluume, thanks I tried your method and it works. But, the problem is that even though the JDialog stays up front, I can still use controls in the parent frame (Only one dialog can be accessed at a time). If you have a solution to that I would be glad to hear it. But otherwise its OK, because I will just close the current JDialog if a next dialog is opened. Thanks again.